# Lazy-loading items in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am implementing a custom TableCellFactory to load data asynchronously from a database. Querying the db should not block the UI thread.

```
public abstract class AsynchronousTableCellFactory<E, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<E, T>, TableCell<E, T>> {

private static final Executor exe1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

private static final Executor exe2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

@Override
public TableCell<E, T> call(final TableColumn<E, T> param) {
    final TableCell<E, T> cell = new TableCell<E, T>() {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final T item, final boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText("Thinking..");
                // do this later some time, we need to finish here FAST
                exe1.execute(() -> {

                    if (getTableRow() != null) {
                        final Service<T> service = new Service<T>() {

                            @Override
                            protected Task<T> createTask() {
                                return getTask((E) getTableRow().getItem());
                            }
                        };
                        service.setExecutor(exe2);
                        service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {

                            if (e.getSource().getValue() == null) {
                                setText("n/a");
                            } else {
                                setText(e.getSource().getValue().toString());
                            }

                        });
                        service.setOnFailed(e -> {
                            final Throwable t = e.getSource().getException();
                            setText(t.getLocalizedMessage());
                        });
                        service.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    return cell;
}

protected abstract Task<T> getTask(E rowDataItem);

}
```

It is working most of the time, but not always. One strange thing about it is that `T item` is always `null`.
**In which cases can I expect `T item` to be `null`?**

The corresponding table code:

```
public class OriginsTableViewController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<LazyLoadingOriginWrapper> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LazyLoadingOriginWrapper, String> cSampleName;

@Override
public void initialize(final URL location, final ResourceBundle resources) {
    cSampleName.setCellFactory(new AsynchronousOriginTableCellFactory<>(e -> e.getSampleName()));
```

}

**EDIT:** Find the better approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037141/lazy-loading-fxproperties).

Comment: just for emphasis: _never-ever_ do any heavy lifting in a Cell! That's the task of the data layer, _always_ (as correctly done by n247s in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48963048/203657 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that a `TableCell` is reusable! this means any item can be assigned to any cell (that's what the `updateItem` method is for). Your current code can provide a lot of problems as your completion handlers set a `TableCell`'s text directly.

An easy solution is wrapping the result in a `ObservableValue` inside your `LazyLoadingOriginWrapper` and use that in a `CellValueFactory` rather than creating your own `TableCell`. Updates of the `ObservableValue` will be vissible inside the `TableView` (make sure you modify the `ObservableValue` on the 'fx-application' thread!). e.g.

```
public static class LazyLoadingOriginWrapper
{
    // params are 'bean', 'id/name', 'default value'
    ObservableStringValue name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "thinking...");

    public ObservableStringValue nameProperty() { return name; }

    public void setName(String value)
    {
         Platform.runLater(() -> name.set(value));
     }

    // add your logic for asynchronious loading here and update the above ObservableValue instead. Make sure you trigger it manually!
}

@Override
public void initialize(final URL location, final ResourceBundle resources) {
    cSampleName.setCellValueFactory(C -> C.getValue().nameProperty());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That's it, just figured it out! **Use CellValueFactory instead of CellFactory**.

Comment: Updating the ObservableValue in the LazyLoadingElementWrapper is the cleanest approach, thanks a lot!

Comment: good answer - just a bit of nitpicking: make sure to do the update of the wrapper property on the fx-application thread