# Lazy-loading FXProperties

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

This is a follow-up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962796/lazy-loading-items-in-tableview).

I am implementing a table, that loads data asynchronously into the table cells. The problem is, that the table cells sometimes do not update correctly. Sometimes it somehow 'hangs' and **shows "Loading.." forever**. The actual value updates only when I scroll in the table a little bit.

[image]

**To reproduce**, run the application an scroll down fast in the table. Some cells will not show the 'lazily-loaded' value but the placeholder string.

The lazy-loading property looks like this:

```
public abstract class LazyLoadingStringProperty extends SimpleStringProperty {

public static final String DEFAULT_LOADING_STRING = "Loading..";
private static final ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private String loadingString = DEFAULT_LOADING_STRING;

private boolean loaded = false;

public LazyLoadingStringProperty() {

}

public boolean isLoaded() {
    return loaded;
}

public void setLoaded(final boolean loaded) {
    this.loaded = loaded;
}

public String getLoadingString() {
    return loadingString;
}

public void setLoadingString(final String loadingString) {
    this.loadingString = loadingString;
}

@Override
public String getValue() {
    if (!loaded) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> startLoadingService());
        return loadingString;
    }
    return super.getValue();
}

protected void startLoadingService() {

    final Service<String> s = new Service<String>() {

        @Override
        protected Task<String> createTask() {
            return LazyLoadingStringProperty.this.createTask();
        }
    };

    s.setExecutor(exe);

    s.setOnFailed(e -> {
        setLoaded(true);
        setValue(s.getException().getLocalizedMessage());

    });

    s.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        setLoaded(true);
        setValue(s.getValue());

    });
    s.start();
    // System.err.println("Started");
}

protected abstract Task<String> createTask();
```

}

The Applikation looks like this:

```
public class ExampleTable extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 500;

    private final TableView<ExampleBean> table = new TableView<>();

    private final ObservableList<ExampleBean> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final TableColumn<ExampleBean, String> c1 = new TableColumn<>("A");
        c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExampleBean, String>("p1"));
        final TableColumn<ExampleBean, String> c2 = new TableColumn<>("B");
        c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExampleBean, String>("p2"));
        final TableColumn<ExampleBean, String> c3 = new TableColumn<>("C");
        c3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExampleBean, String>("p3"));

        c1.setPrefWidth(100);
        c2.setPrefWidth(100);
        c3.setPrefWidth(100);


        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
            data.add(new ExampleBean());
        }

        final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(table);
        sp.setMaxHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        sp.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        sp.setFitToHeight(true);
        sp.setFitToWidth(true);

        table.setItems(data);
        // table.setMaxHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        // table.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        table.getColumns().addAll(c1, c2, c3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        VBox.setVgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(sp);

        scene.setRoot(vbox);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The complete runnable code can be found [here](https://github.com/kerner1000/asynchronous-table-loading).

Comment: I think what is missing is that you need to call `fireValueChangedEvent()` in the `onSucceeded()` and `onFailed()` methods, so that listeners get notified there is a new value available.

Comment: This is/ should be done in the `setValue()` method, not? I will give it a try.

Comment: But `setValue()` isn't invoked when the loading task finishes...

Comment: I call it in the `onSucceeded()` and `onFailed()` methods.

Comment: Oh, but you call it *before* you call `setLoaded()`... so listeners get notified but they still get the "not yet loaded" value

Comment: I tried it, adding a manual call to fireValueChangeEvent. Doesn't help..

Comment: I now call first `setLoaded()`, still the same..

Comment: Hmm. The service seems completely unnecessary; all you actually need is a task (there's no point in using a service just once: the whole purpose of it is that it's reusable).  I added the `fireValueChangeEvent()` call and removed the service (just using a task), and then it worked fine. That bothers me though: I don't know why the service prevents it working properly.

Comment: I also replaced `Service` with `Task` and changed `startLoadingService()` to be called immediately instead of via `runLater()`. No explicit `fireValueChangeEvent()`. Seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It looks like a bug in JavaFX Service ...</strike>

As there are no saved references to `Service` instances they are garbage collected.
And sometimes some of them are garbage collected before their tasks are finished.
In this case listeners of `onFailed` and `onSucceeded` properties of a service are not called.

The simple resolution is to save services references with `LazyLoadingStringProperty` object:

```
...
private ArrayList<Service<String>> services = new ArrayList<>();

protected void startLoadingService() {

    final Service<String> s = new Service<String>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<String> createTask() {
            return LazyLoadingStringProperty.this.createTask();
        }
    };
    services.add(s);
    ...
```

But there is no need to load one value with many tasks in parallel.
So one service per value is more than enough:

```
    ...

    private Service<String> s;

    protected void startLoadingService() {

        if (s != null) return; // started already

        s = new Service<String>() {
            ...
```