# CheckBoxTableCell not working with ObjectProperty<Boolean>

Tags: java, javafx

I extended `SimpleObjectProperty<T>` to create a custom, lazy-loading implementation ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037141/lazy-loading-fxproperties)), `LazyLoadingObjectProperty<T>`.

To use this generic implementation for a boolean property, I use `LazyLoadingObjectProperty<Boolean>`.

In my table, I want to render the boolean property as a `CheckBox`.

Nevertheless, **`CheckBoxTableCell` seems to work only with `BooleanProperty` but not with `ObjectProperty<Boolean>`**.

Why is that and how can I workaround?

Here is some code:

```
public class ExampleTable extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 5000;

    private final TableView<ExampleBean> table = new TableView<>();

    private final ObservableList<ExampleBean> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final TableColumn<ExampleBean, Boolean> c1 = new TableColumn<>("A");
        c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExampleBean, Boolean>("p1"));
        c1.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(c1));
        c1.setEditable(true);
        c1.setPrefWidth(100);

        final TableColumn<ExampleBean, String> c2 = new TableColumn<>("B");
        c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExampleBean, String>("p2"));
        c2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        c2.setEditable(true);
        c2.setPrefWidth(100);


        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
            data.add(new ExampleBean());
        }

        final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(table);
        sp.setMaxHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        sp.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        sp.setFitToHeight(true);
        sp.setFitToWidth(true);

        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setItems(data);
        // table.setMaxHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        // table.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        table.getColumns().addAll(c1, c2);

        final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        cm.getItems().add(new MenuItem("bu"));
        table.setContextMenu(cm);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        VBox.setVgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(sp);

        scene.setRoot(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

public class ExampleBean {

    private ObjectProperty<Boolean> p1;

    private ObjectProperty<String> p2;


    public ExampleBean() {
        p1 = new SimpleObjectProperty(true);
        p1.addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            System.err.println("Value changed " + ov + " -> " + nv);
        });

        p2 = new SimpleObjectProperty(Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt()));
        p2.addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            System.err.println("Value changed " + ov + " -> " + nv);
        });
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Boolean> p1Property() {
        return this.p1;
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<String> p2Property() {
        return this.p2;
    }
}
```

Note that the property is initialized with `Boolean.TRUE` and the CheckBoxCells are not checked.

Not used/ needed for this question:

```
public abstract class LazyLoadingObjectProperty<T> extends SimpleObjectProperty<T> {

    public LazyLoadingObjectProperty() {
        super();

    }

    public LazyLoadingObjectProperty(final Object bean, final String name, final T initialValue) {
        super(bean, name, initialValue);

    }

    public LazyLoadingObjectProperty(final Object bean, final String name) {
        super(bean, name);

    }

    public LazyLoadingObjectProperty(final T initialValue) {
        super(initialValue);

    }

    private boolean loaded = false;

    private final ChangeListener<T> valueChangeListener = (o, ov, nv) -> {
        valueExternallyUpdated(nv);
    };

    /**
     * Is called after the background task's finished (success or failure). Override
     * if needed. E.g. to bind the value afterwards.
     */
    protected void afterLoaded() {
        addListener(valueChangeListener);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Task} that will calculate this Property's value in the
     * background.
     *
     * @return a {@link Task} that will calculate this Property's value in the
     *         background.
     */
    protected abstract Task<T> createTask();

    protected T getFailedValue(final Throwable t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        if (!loaded) {
            startLoadingService();
        }
        return super.getValue();
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() {
        return loaded;
    }

    public void setLoaded(final boolean loaded) {



        // the loaded property has been reset manually. Remove change listener
        if (this.loaded && !loaded) {
            removeListener(valueChangeListener);
        }

        this.loaded = loaded;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(final T v) {
        super.setValue(v);
    }

    /**
     * Starts the {@link Task} that will calculate this Property's value in the
     * background.
     */
    protected void startLoadingService() {
        setLoaded(true);
        final Task<T> s = LazyLoadingObjectProperty.this.createTask();

        LazyLoadingThreads.getExecutorService().submit(s);

        s.setOnFailed(e -> {
            setValue(getFailedValue(e.getSource().getException()));
            afterLoaded();
        });

        s.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            setValue(s.getValue());
            afterLoaded();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Override this callback method to handle external value-change-events
     * (not-lazily-loaded). This callback is only called, if the value is updated
     * manually, i.e., not via the lazy-loading mechanism.
     *
     * @param nv
     *            the new value
     */
    protected void valueExternallyUpdated(final T nv) {
        // override if needed

    }

}
```

Find the mwe also [here](https://github.com/kerner1000/checkboxtablecell_booleanobjectproperty).

Comment: Looks like a bug (though I need to spend a bit more time to be sure about that). Possible workaround is to define a `BooleanProperty` in your model class and bind it bidirectionally to the `ObjectProperty<Boolean>`. Then use the `BooleanProperty` in the table.

Comment: That workaround is working nicely, Thanks so much!

Comment: @James_D agreed on a bug: the doc'ed signature of the callback is ObservableValue<Boolean>, the actual bidi-binding to checkBox.selected only happens if it is of type BooleanProperty .. crap :(

Comment: *bidi-binding to checkBox.selected only happens if it is of type BooleanProperty* Can you post a link to the code?

Comment: look at the source of checkBoxTableCell: the binding happens (or not) in updateItem

Comment: Source code is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell). The documentation claims it bidirectionally binds to an `ObservableValue<Boolean>`, which is clearly nonsense in the first place...

Comment: @James_D certainly true - but  a bit nitpicking: what it meant to doc probably was that it could be useful for read-only values .. ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Absolutely, but then the docs shouldn't say "bidirectionally". Should be "binds to the `ObservableValue<Boolean>`; additionally, if the `ObservableValue<Boolean> is an instance of XXX, then the binding is bidirectional". The lack of specification of XXX is the cause of the issue here.

Comment: @James_D yeah :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a bug, at least in doc but also in implementation: the automatic bidi-binding between the checkBox' selected and the observableValue at index - if possible - is *the* design intention. The implemenation fails to meet that requirement, even when it could.

A quick hack is a custom subclass that fixes the error, something like (not formally tested, beware!):

```
public static class FixedCheckBoxTableCell<S, T> extends CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        checkCallback();
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
    }

    private void checkCallback() {
        if (getSelectedStateCallback() != null) return;
        ObservableValue<Boolean> observable = 
                (ObservableValue<Boolean>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
        // handled by super
        if (observable instanceof BooleanProperty) return;
        // can't bidi-bind anyway
        if (!(observable instanceof Property)) return;
        // getting here if we have a ObjectProperty<Boolean>, that's not handled by super
        setSelectedStateCallback(index -> {
            ObjectProperty<Boolean> p = (ObjectProperty<Boolean>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(index);
            return BooleanProperty.booleanProperty(p);
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Solved this by bidi-binding the `ObjectProperty<Boolean>` to a helper property of type `BooleanProperty`, as *James_D* suggested.

Comment: valid approach,  certainly - but you have to remember doing it with every property ;) Personally, I prefer to handle where it is broken .. and someone should file a bug ... sigh

Comment: True, but the `FixedCheckBoxTableCell` I also have to remember to use everytime ;) Same thing I think. I will file a bug.. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Filed a bug (9052917), I will post the link here as soon as it is available.

Comment: I've used my own implementations (from scratch, not subclassing `CheckBoxTableCell`); it just doesn't really seem natural to be to have a `Callback<Integer, XXX>` (XXX is `Property<Boolean>` or whatever...). Prefer to use something like a `Function<S, Property<Boolean>>` that maps the *item* (not its index) to a property.

Comment: *James_D*, you mean you reimplemented `CheckBoxTableCell`? Can you post some code?

Comment: @James_D hmm .. passing the index sounds okay to me: it's the central "position" (in the items) property of an IndexedCell and likely to be correct always. It's one of two options to stay in-line with column api, which allows access its observable by either index or rowItem. The latter poses more work into the  cell as it must lookup the rowItem. For me, a mere judgement call at the end of day :) What really bothers me is the by-pass of the normal edit mechanism - a cell _must not_ change the data, ever, IMO.

Comment: The issue is online now. bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8199320. Apparently, this is a known issue since 2014..

Comment: `kleopatra` I agree on the edit mechanism, the whole class is more like a student's hack ;)

Comment: wow .. nearly 4 years and nothing happened :( At the end of the day, it's a trivial fix but obviously nobody (including users/the former reporter) cared ...